# GNSSの測位間隔について

Tags: spresense

SPRESENSEで測位間隔の5Hz指定は可能でしょうか。
Spresense SDKのGNSSのサンプルコード(gnss/gnss_main.c)では、

```cpp
set_opemode.cycle    = 1000;  /* Position notify cycle(msec step). */
```

としており、200msecが指定可能なように見えたのですが、struct cxd56_gnss_ope_mode_param_s のコメントを見ると、

```cpp
/** Positioning cycle[ms]\n
 *  The cycle data is 1000msec aligned only and
 *  cannot set 0msec.\n
 *  (Init value 1000) */
```

とあり、1000msec単位でしか指定できないように見えます。

Answer (score 3):

回答が待ちきれず、実際にボードを購入して、試してみました。
結果、5Hz出力はできました。
コメントの「1000msec aligned only」は何なのか、不明ですが。。。
精度に問題が出るとか、消費電力が上がるとかなのかも。
そう思うことにします。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
ご返事が遅くなり、大変申し訳ありません。
また、SPRESENSEのご購入誠にありがとうございます。

お問い合わせいただきましたGNSSの測位間隔ですが、
現状、弊社で性能を保証している最小測位間隔は`1sec(1Hz)`になります。

それ以下の測位間隔の対応については現在検討しております。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
5Hz出力ですが、色々と試したところ、遅延や抜けが発生することが分かりました。
現在対応を検討中とのことですので、楽しみに待つことにします。
よろしくお願いいたします。